# Java Array list contains and set value

Tags: java, arraylist

I am adding A, B and C to array list. how can I check if array list contains A, B and C than set id variable as 1. Or is there a better way to do this. I just want to set id variable as 1,2 or 3 depending upon the value inside Array list. For example if array list contains A, B and C than id = 1 and if array list contains A, B, C and D than id = 2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ArrayList.contains(Object elem)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method for this purpose. It returns

> true if the specified element is present; false otherwise.

A small code snippet to give you some idea.

```
int id = 0;
ArrayList<String> arraylist  = new ArrayList<String>();
arraylist.add("A");
arraylist.add("B");
arraylist.add("C");
if(arraylist.contains("A") && arraylist.contains("B"))
     id=1;
System.out.println(id)
```

So, Output = `1`.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: I think you didn't noticed the statement "snippet to give you `some idea`".

Comment: @RanRag sorry msised that make an eidt and i will give you back the points :)

Answer (score 2):

You would use the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method that is exposed in the List interface.  The logic that you need to determine what to set the id at is going to be whatever rules you have.  My guess in this contrived example it is going to be if A && B && C  id = 1

Remember to override `equals` and `hashcode` or there is not a guarantee that `list.contains` will return the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the notes about equals/hash, I would add the simplification of using `List.containsAll()`:

```
int id = 0;
List forId1 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
List forId2 = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
if (mylist.containsAll(forId2) {
     id=2;
} else if (mylist.containsAll(forId1) {
     id=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your putting custom objects in the array the you need to implement an equals and hashCode method on it, the you can use the contains method of the ArrayList class.